# is there a way to shorten an existing array of strings for weekdays via moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

is there a way to shorten an array of weekdays via moment.js e.g. `['Monday', 'Wednesday']` to `['Mon', 'Wed']`?

I been digging into its doc but haven't found a way to do that. The relevant part of the doc is this link https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/07-customization/05-weekday-min/ It seems like it would output all of the abbreviations instead of converting an array of existing weekday strings to their abbreviations.

Comment: Moment is language-neutral, so almost certainly not.

Comment: an easy enough thing to map()

Comment: Do you want it as 3 letters each or the common shorthands `['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri']`. 3 would be very easy (only keep `day.slice(0,3)`), and the latter would be a bit more complicated with having to manually check for each position (`switch` statement, chained `.replace(..., ...)`'s, etc.)

Comment: also, why are you exclusively looking to do this with moment.js? Even if your project uses it as a dependency, their site clearly states there "may be better alternatives" and try to steer you in a different direction.

Comment: @Pointy The framework itself might be, but your sentiment is incorrect, because locale support in Moment is [through the roof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoVL.png).

Comment: @zcoop98 that's my point: an automatic way of shortening words that represent days of the week would be extremely hard (basically impossible) to work on all locales. Indeed, the linked guidance in the question is basically the only practical way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with Moment and came around this solution:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const weekdays = {
  'Monday': 1,
  'Tuesday': 2,
  'Wednesday': 3,
  'Thursday': 4,
  'Friday': 5,
  'Saturday': 6,
  'Sunday': 7,
}

const arr = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

const modifiedArr = arr.map((day) => moment(moment().day(weekdays[day])).format('dd'));

console.log(modifiedArr) // ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa']
```

Not sure though that it's more useful than just usual `map` and `slice(0,2)`

Comment: The main question is ambiguous, this answer is not wrong, a bit complex, but in my opinion it is not wrong. I don't understand why it was voted negatively without even explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an separate array of days with the first 2 chars of day's name you do like that:

```js
const array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) array.push(moment().day(i).format('dd'));

console.log(array) // [ 'Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa' ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Else if you want replace the locale of moment you can use what you linked, but I found a problem, the field of object is not `weekdaysMin` but `weekdaysShort`

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  weekdaysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa']
});

console.log('Today is: ', moment().format('ddd'));

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) console.log(moment().startOf('week').add(i, 'days').format('ddd'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```